# Como perguntar ao PDO se a inserção foi feita ou deu erro?

Tags: php, pdo

Como perguntar ao `$Produtos` se a inserção foi feita ou se houve algum erro na tentativa de inserção tipo o `or die` do `mysql`?

```
    if(isset($_POST['cadastra_produtos'])){
    ///////////////////////////////////

    $Produtos = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_produtos VALUES 
    (NULL, :prod_nome, :prod_categoria, :prod_dimens, :prod_qtde, :prod_valor, :prod_descr, :prod_data)");

    $Produtos->execute(array(
        prod_nome       => strip_tags($_POST['prod_nome']), 
        prod_categoria  => strip_tags($_POST['prod_categoria']),    
        prod_dimens     => strip_tags($_POST['prod_dimens']),   
        prod_qtde       => strip_tags($_POST['prod_valor']),    
        prod_valor      => strip_tags($_POST['prod_valor']),    
        prod_descr      => strip_tags($_POST['prod_descr']),    
        prod_data       => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O [`execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) retorna `false` se a operação falhar. Você também pode pegar informações adicionais sobre o erro com o [`errorInfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php):

```
$Produtos = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_produtos VALUES 
(NULL, :prod_nome, :prod_categoria, :prod_dimens, :prod_qtde, :prod_valor, :prod_descr, :prod_data)");

$ok = $Produtos->execute(array(
    'prod_nome'       => strip_tags($_POST['prod_nome']), 
    'prod_categoria'  => strip_tags($_POST['prod_categoria']),    
    'prod_dimens'     => strip_tags($_POST['prod_dimens']),   
    'prod_qtde'       => strip_tags($_POST['prod_valor']),    
    'prod_valor'      => strip_tags($_POST['prod_valor']),    
    'prod_descr'      => strip_tags($_POST['prod_descr']),    
    'prod_data'       => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
));

if(!$ok) {
    print_r($Produtos->errorInfo());
}
```

<sup>**PS:** Use aspas nos nomes das chaves da array (funciona sem por uma particularidade do PHP, mas não é correto)</sup>

Answer (score 7):

O ideal é se valer do modelo Orientado a Objetos da PDO também para os erros, pegando as [PDOException](http://php.net/PDOException) disparadas quando algum erro ocorrer:

```
try {

    $stmt = $conn -> prepare( /* ... */ );

    try {

        $stmt -> execute();

    } catch( PDOException $e ) {

        // Statement não foi executado
    }

} catch( PDOException $e ) {

    // Statement não preparado

    echo $e -> getMessage();
}
```

Mas... Tem um pequeno inconveniente. Por padrão a PDO prefere ficar quietinha quanto aos erros, sem reportá-los, mesmo que seus alertas de erro estejam habilitados e em nível suficiente para que erros sejam reportados.

Sendo assim, para que ela grite aos quatro ventos quando qualquer coisa machucar ela, você deve configurar o objeto de conexão, depois de criado:

```
$dbh = new PDO( /* ... */ );

$dbh -> setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

Answer (score 0):

Dá para fazer o seguinte:

```
if(isset($_POST['cadastra_produtos'])){
    ///////////////////////////////////

    $Produtos = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_produtos VALUES 
    (NULL, :prod_nome, :prod_categoria, :prod_dimens, :prod_qtde, :prod_valor, :prod_descr, :prod_data)");

    if($Produtos->execute(array(
        prod_nome       => strip_tags($_POST['prod_nome']), 
        prod_categoria  => strip_tags($_POST['prod_categoria']),    
        prod_dimens     => strip_tags($_POST['prod_dimens']),   
        prod_qtde       => strip_tags($_POST['prod_valor']),    
        prod_valor      => strip_tags($_POST['prod_valor']),    
        prod_descr      => strip_tags($_POST['prod_descr']),    
        prod_data       => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ))){

        if($Produtos->rowCount() > 0){
           echo "inserido com sucesso";
        }else{
           echo "ocorreu um erro!";
        }

    }else{
        echo "ocorreu um erro!";
    }
```

Comment: Considere dar uma explicação do que seu exemplo faz, um usuário inexperiente vai copiar seu código e continuar sem saber o que acontece. Além de disparar um `undefined constant prod_nome`.

Answer (score -1):

Só usar isso após o execute():

```php
$stmt->execute();

$foo_arr = $stmt->errorInfo();

print_r($foo_arr);
```